# Authorization by cookie stored JWT token. DRF

Tags: vue.js, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, access-token

I read that store JWT token in cookies is a secure way to protect it from XSS. But I don't understand how to send access_token to endpoint with is_authenticated middleware.
How to provide access_token from cookies to request for check is_authenticated middleware?

I tried the following and want to show authenticated user:
My Vue request:

```
 async created() {
    const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
    await axios.post(baseURL + 'tracker/connection_link', {}, {
        withCredentials: true,
    })
}
```

Django endpoint:

```
@api_view(('GET', 'POST'))
@authentication_classes([JWTAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def get_connection_link(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        print(request.user)
```

It return response with code 401 'Authentication credentials were not provided.'